# How to Split an R List Containing Character Vectors of Varying Lengths Into Specific Columns?

Tags: r, tidyr, tibble

I have some data in JSON format, that using jsonlite I was able to read into a data frame in R. The data I'm working with is in lists, where each list contains character vectors of different lengths. For example:

```
  values
  <list>      
1   A
2   B
3   character(0)
4   C
5   c(A, C)
6   D
7   c(B, C)
8   c(D, E)
```

Or, to reproduce in full:

```
structure(list(values1 = list("C", "E", character(0), "C", character(0), 
    "C", c("D", "A"), c("D", "A"), "D", "D", character(0), "D", 
    "A", "E", "E", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", 
    "E", "E", "A", character(0), "E", character(0), character(0), 
    "B", character(0), "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", character(0), 
    character(0), character(0), character(0), character(0), character(0), 
    character(0), character(0), "E", c("E", "D"), c("E", "D"), 
    "B", "E", "E", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "D", "D", 
    character(0), character(0), character(0), character(0), "B", 
    c("C", "A"), character(0), "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "C", "C", character(0), character(0), character(0), character(0), 
    "E", "E", character(0), character(0), "B", "E", "A", "C", 
    "B", "C", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", character(0), 
    "A", character(0), "A", "D", "B", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", 
    "C", "A", "A", "B", "D", "D", character(0), character(0), 
    character(0), character(0), character(0), character(0), "C", 
    "B", character(0), "B", character(0), "B", "E", "D", c("C", 
    "E"), c("C", "E"), "D", "D", "C", "C", character(0), "C", 
    character(0), "C", "C", "D", "E", "E", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
    "B", "B", "E", character(0), character(0), character(0), 
    character(0), "B", "B", "E", "A", character(0), "B", "A", 
    character(0), "A", "D", "D", c("D", "A"), c("D", "A"), c("D", 
    "B"), c("D", "B"), character(0), "E", character(0), "E", 
    "E", "E", "E", character(0), "D", character(0), "E", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "D", c("B", "A"), c("B", "A"), "C", 
    character(0), character(0), "B", "E", "E", "B", c("E", "B"
    ), "A", "A", "B", "B", "D", "D", "A", "A", character(0), 
    "A", "C", character(0), "C", "C", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", 
    "B", "A", "E", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", c("C", "E"), character(0), 
    character(0), character(0), character(0), "E", c("E", "A"
    ), "E", character(0), character(0), "A", "D", "D", c("D", 
    "A"), c("D", "A"), character(0), character(0), character(0), 
    character(0), character(0), character(0), "B", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "B", "B", c("C", "E"), c("C", "E"), "E", "C", "C", 
    "C", c("E", "D", "B", "A"), c("E", "D", "B", "A"), character(0), 
    "A", character(0), "A", c("C", "A"), c("C", "A"), c("C", 
    "A"), "E", "E", "A", character(0), "C", c("E", "D"), c("E", 
    "D"), character(0), character(0), character(0), character(0), 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "E", c("C", "D"), "E", character(0), 
    character(0), character(0), "D", "D", character(0), "A", 
    "B", character(0), character(0), character(0), character(0), 
    "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "D", "D", "B", "B", "B", "E", "D", 
    "C", "D", "C", "C", "E", "E", "A", character(0), character(0), 
    "B", character(0), "B", "B", "B", "B", character(0), "A", 
    "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", character(0), "D", character(0), 
    "D", "B", "A", character(0), "B", "D", "A", "A", character(0), 
    "A", "D", "D", "E", "E", "B", character(0), character(0), 
    character(0), "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "A", "D", c("C", "B"
    ), character(0), "D", "C", "C", character(0), character(0), 
    "D", "D", "D", c("B", "A"), "E", "A", "A", character(0), 
    "E", "C", "B", character(0), character(0), character(0), 
    character(0), "E", "E", "D", "C", "C", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
    character(0), "E", "E", "A", "B", "A", "A", "D", "E", "E", 
    "B", "B", character(0), character(0), "D", "D", "C", "D", 
    "D", "E", character(0), "E", character(0), "E", c("D", "B"
    ), character(0), "B", character(0), character(0), "D", character(0), 
    "D", "D", "D", "C", character(0), "E", "E", c("E", "B"), 
    c("E", "B"), "E", "E", "D", "D", "B", c("E", "A"), c("E", 
    "A"), c("C", "D"), c("C", "D"), c("C", "B"), c("C", "B"), 
    character(0), "C", "B"), values2 = list("C", "E", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", c("D", "A"), c("D", "A"), "D", "D", "D", "D", 
    "A", "E", "E", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", 
    "E", "E", "A", "E", "E", character(0), "B", "B", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", c("E", "A"), c("E", "A"), c("E", "A"), 
    c("E", "A"), c("C", "A"), c("C", "A"), c("C", "A"), c("C", 
    "A"), "E", c("E", "D"), c("E", "D"), "B", "E", "E", "A", 
    "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "D", "D", c("C", "B"), c("C", 
    "B"), c("C", "B"), c("C", "B"), "B", c("C", "A"), character(0), 
    "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", c("E", "D"), c("E", 
    "D"), c("E", "D"), c("E", "D"), "E", "E", character(0), character(0), 
    "B", "E", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "B", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", 
    "C", "A", "A", "B", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", character(0), 
    character(0), "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "E", "D", c("C", 
    "E"), c("C", "E"), "D", "D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "D", "E", "E", "B", "B", "C", "C", "B", "B", "E", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "E", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", 
    "D", "D", c("D", "A"), c("D", "A"), c("D", "B"), c("D", "B"
    ), "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "D", "D", "E", "E", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "D", c("B", "A"), c("B", "A"
    ), "C", character(0), character(0), "B", "E", "E", "B", c("E", 
    "B"), "A", "A", "B", "B", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "E", "C", 
    "C", "D", "D", "D", c("C", "E"), "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", 
    c("E", "A"), "E", character(0), character(0), "A", "D", "D", 
    c("D", "A"), c("D", "A"), c("D", "A"), c("D", "A"), c("D", 
    "A"), c("D", "A"), c("D", "A"), c("D", "A"), "B", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "B", "B", c("C", "E"), c("C", "E"), "E", "C", "C", 
    "C", c("E", "D", "B", "A"), c("E", "D", "B", "A"), "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", c("C", "A"), c("C", "A"), c("C", "A"), "E", "E", 
    "A", "C", "C", c("E", "D"), c("E", "D"), "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "E", c("C", "D"), "E", character(0), 
    character(0), character(0), "D", "D", character(0), "A", 
    "B", c("D", "B"), c("D", "B"), c("D", "B"), c("D", "B"), 
    "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "D", "D", "B", "B", "B", "E", "D", 
    "C", "D", "C", "C", "E", "E", "A", character(0), "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", 
    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "B", "A", "B", "B", "D", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "D", "D", "E", "E", "B", character(0), character(0), 
    character(0), "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "A", "D", c("C", "B"
    ), "D", "D", "C", "C", character(0), "D", "D", "D", "D", 
    c("B", "A"), "E", "A", "A", character(0), "E", "C", "B", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "E", "E", "D", "C", "C", "E", "E", "E", 
    "E", "E", "E", "E", "A", "B", c("C", "E", "D", "B", "A"), 
    c("C", "E", "D", "B", "A"), "D", "E", "E", "B", "B", character(0), 
    character(0), "D", "D", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
    "E", c("D", "B"), "B", "B", character(0), "D", "D", "D", 
    "D", "D", "D", "C", "E", "E", "E", c("E", "B"), c("E", "B"
    ), "E", "E", "D", "D", "B", c("E", "A"), c("E", "A"), c("C", 
    "D"), c("C", "D"), c("C", "B"), c("C", "B"), "C", "C", "B")), row.names = c(NA, 
445L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to split this data up so that each value gets its own column:

```
       1      2      3     4      5
     <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
1      A
2            B
3    
4                   C
5      A            C
6                          D
7            B      C
8                          D      E
```

Then, ultimately, get the data into a tidy format so that it's easy to filter by a column:

```
       A      B      C     D     E
    <logi> <logi> <logi> <logi> <logi>
1    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
2    FALSE TRUE   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
3    FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
4    FALSE FALSE  TRUE   FALSE  FALSE
5    TRUE  FALSE  TRUE   FALSE  FALSE
6    FALSE FALSE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE
7    FALSE TRUE   TRUE   FALSE  FALSE
8    FALSE FALSE  FALSE  TRUE   TRUE
```

That last step should be simple with mutate, it's the splitting I can't figure out. I'm aware of both tidyr `separate` and `unnest_wider`, but as far as I can tell those don't let me control which columns the vector is split into.

Comment: Can you provide your data using `dput` so that we can copy the data and use?

Comment: `qdapTools::mtabulate(df$values)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is something like this :

```
df <- structure(list(values = list("A", "B", character(0), "C", c("A", 
"C"), "D", c("B", "C"), c("D", "E"))), 
 row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

You can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  unnest(values) %>%
  complete(row = 1:max(row)) %>%
  mutate(val = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = values, values_from = val, values_fill = FALSE) %>%
  dplyr::select(-`NA`, -row)

#    A     B     C     D     E    
#  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#1 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#2 FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
#3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#4 FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE
#5 TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE
#6 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#7 FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE
#8 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `dput`, data, we can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>% 
  unnest(value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = name, 
  values_fill = FALSE, values_fn = list(name = ~ length(.) > 0)) %>% 
 select(-rn)


# A tibble: 422 x 5
#   C     E     D     A     B    
#   <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
# 1 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 2 FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 3 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 4 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 5 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 6 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 7 FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
# 8 FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
# 9 FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE
#10 FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE
# … with 412 more rows
```